# using logger for prefect Tasks like prefect.tasks.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery

Tags: python, prefect

How can I add a logger to prefect's `prefect.tasks.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery` class just like with the `@task` decorator e.g.:

```
from prefect import task, Flow
import prefect
from time import sleep


@task()
def some_task():
    logger = prefect.context.get("logger")
    logger.info("Let's sleep a second!")
    sleep(1)


version_check = prefect.tasks.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery(
    db="sqlite.db",
    query="Select sqlite_version()",
)


with Flow("a flow") as flow:

    some_task()
    print(version_check)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    flow.run()
```

Currently, only `some_task` is logged. How can I log precast tasks like SQLiteQuery ?
(prefect 1.0 family)

Comment: I think the issue here is that version_check is not called in the Flow? You can try:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is that version_check is not called in the Flow? You can try:

```py
with Flow("a flow") as flow:

    some_task()
    version_check()
```

In the current form, it is just initialized but not added to the flow. You also can't print the output with the standard python print. The print will just print the Task class. You need to log from inside a task.

```
@task
def log_something(x):
    prefect.context.logger.info(x)
    return
```

and then use it in the flow:

```
with Flow("a flow") as flow:

    some_task()
    x = version_check()
    log_something(x)
```

Comment: yep, forgot the brackets. Now the Task 'SQLiteQuery is logged (starting/finishing). The additional `log_something` task is kind of a solution to log version_check's output, but I'd prefer to do it **within version_check itself**. Any idea how to log directly ?

Comment: You can't really because it needs to be inserted in the task code. So you can call a task in another task by using task.run(). You need a new task that calls version check inside and adds logging similar to how I used the logger in the answer